# Winforms SplitContainer always displaying split cursor

Tags: winforms

I'm new to winForms, I'm trying just to create a simple SplitPanel.
I just drag it from the tools.

The problem is that if I move the mouse over the panel, the cursor shows the "split cursor", even if it is not over the split divise or even if I add some controls inside it.

I can't figure why and can't find nothing related to this (I don't attached a printscreen cause it hides the mouse and the problem is simple to explain)
Can this be a framework problem?

Comment: That does not happen unless you have set the `Cursor` property of the `SplitContainer`'s parent control to a value other than `Default`. The `Cursor` is an [ambient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property. Reset the `Cursor` property of the `SplitContainer`.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's really an installation problem.
I have created a new project, droped the SplitPanel and hit play.

Comment: Man, after reinstalled everything, I realize the problem and now I feel like the dumbest developer on the earth.
The Splitpanel has the cursor set to default. but not in the inner pannels, I don't know why, but even a fresh new SplitPanel is created with the cursor set to VSplit in it's panels.

Comment: No problem. It happens.